# XPath to check if all provided pairs of elements exist for an entry

Tags: sql-server-2008, xpath

I have the following XML stored in an XML field in a SQL Server 2008 database.

```
<attributes>
  <attribute>
    <key>animal</key>
    <value>rat</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <key>color</key>
    <value>black</value>
  </attribute>
</attributes>
```

I'm able to select all the entries from the table which have an 'animal' key with a value of 'rats' with the following xpath in sql.

```
SELECT *
FROM XmlEvents
WHERE Attributes.exist('/attributes/attribute[key="animal" and value="rat"]') = 1
```

How would I check for matches with multiple attributes?

I'm trying to find rows where: (Key=Animal & Value=Rat) AND (Key=Color & Value=Black).

*(Yes, I could put another .exist with an AND in my WHERE clause but I'm trying to avoid that)*

Bonus points if you can lead me in the right direction to make this some-what dynamic. I would love to have a stored procedure or function which could somehow take a list of Key/Value pairs and find all the rows which match everything provided.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a second `AND EXISTS`?  Do you think it's going to lead to better performance?

Comment: I wanted to compare all possibilities. Do you think an AND EXISTS will perform better than the xpath provided by Markusk?

Comment: +1 to question for being the only documentation i could find that a `.exist() = 1` syntax exists in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath allows nested predicates and multiple predicates. You could write

```
/attributes[attribute[key="animal" and value="rat"]][attribute[key="color" and value="black"]]
```

or equivalently, but somewhat shorter

```
/attributes[attribute[key="animal"]/value="rat" and attribute[key="color"]/value="black"]
```